# pythonw.exe has stopped working

Tags: python, graph-algorithm, strongly-connected-graph

I'm implementing Kosaraju’s two-pass algorithm that can calculate strongly connected components in a directed graph.

I can get the correct result with small input data, but when the input data is larger

([70M txt](https://d18ky98rnyall9.cloudfront.net/_410e934e6553ac56409b2cb7096a44aa_SCC.txt?Expires=1484784000&Signature=gjCF6p7cuL2m~i7GCIvFTfWBDxHTUgW7w8Air3iBI4Rh7g8U-Rwu94s5mQup4kVBggWoO1BvuiYT8LvIOEMxlFy5FSt3Ui4Qz4~xwvMeF5j2Nz~I7E5-jaArjT7w3u1YTjbvIEovr8koSl0gj9gCcwfUMgcI6GNWGPFcS2s2WPc_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A), warning!! this text file has the size of nearly 70M
,using a downloading software with this url to download this large file. If you don't have a downloading software, you can copy this url in your brower `http://pan.baidu.com/s/1i5Hmf5N`
and download it),

it shows "pythonw.exe has stopped working" after about 1 hour. Python should  run to get the correct answer.

How can I fix it? Is there some memory problem?Please do me a favor.

[Here is the large data result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs9ki.png)

My code is here:

```
import time
import datetime
import sys


start = time.time()
print datetime.datetime.now()

with open('test.txt') as f:
    #SCC
    #a = [[int(x) for x in ln.split()] for ln in f]
    data_set_u = []
    data_set_v = []
    for ln in f:
        #print ln
        #print type(ln)
        #print len(ln)
        if len(ln) >1:
            u,v = ln.split()
            u = int(u)
            v = int(v)            
            data_set_u.append(u)
            data_set_v.append(v)
f.close()

print 'open file time: '+ str(time.time() - start) + 's'
print datetime.datetime.now()

sys.setrecursionlimit((max(data_set_u+data_set_v)+ len(data_set_u))*100)

def DFS_Loop():
    num = max(data_set_u+data_set_v)

    start_time_DFS_Loop = time.time()
    global t
    t = 0
    global s
    s = None
    global visited
    visited = [False]* num
    global leader
    leader = [None] * num
    global f
    f = [None] * num


    for i in range(num,0,-1):
        #print i
        #print (i in visited)
        #if (i in visited)==False:
        if visited[i-1] == False:
            s = i
            #print s
            DFS(i)
    print 'end with func DFS_Loop() time: '+ str(time.time() - start_time_DFS_Loop)+ 's'
    print 'end with func DFS_Loop() whole time: '+ str(time.time() - start)+ 's'    
#print data_set_u
#print data_set_v


def DFS(node):
    start_time_DFS = time.time()

    global t
    visited[node-1] = True
    #print visited
    #print visited
    leader[node-1] = s
    #print leader
    arc = []
    arc = [data_set_v[i] for i,x in enumerate(data_set_u) if x==node] 
    #print arc
    for i in arc:
        #print arc
        #print i
        if visited[i-1]==0:
            #print i
            DFS(i)

    t+=1
    #print t
    f[node-1] = t
    #print f
    print 'end with func DFS time: '+ str(time.time() - start_time_DFS)+ 's'
    print 'end with func DFS whole time: '+ str(time.time() - start)+ 's'

DFS_Loop()
print 'DFS_Loop time: '+ str(time.time() - start)+ 's'


##reverse tail and head data
##
##

rev_u,rev_v = data_set_v,data_set_u
new_u = [None] * (len(rev_u))
new_v = [None] * (len(rev_v))
#print rev_v
#print rev_u
for i,val in enumerate(f):
    #rev_u[rev_u.index(i+1)] = val
    #print i+1,val
    #rev_v[rev_v.index(i+1,0,len(rev_v))] = val
    #print rev_v
    #print i,val
    for i_v,val_v in enumerate(rev_v):
        if val_v == i+1:
            #print val_v
            new_v[i_v] = val

    for i_u,val_u in enumerate(rev_u):
        if val_u == i+1:
            #print i_u,val_u
            new_u[i_u] = val    

#print new_u
#print new_v
data_set_u = new_u
data_set_v = new_v
#print data_set_u
#print data_set_v

print 'reverse data time: '+ str(time.time() - start)+ 's'

DFS_Loop()
print 'DFS_Loop time: '+ str(time.time() - start)+ 's'

#print leader


##calculate repeated times appearancing in leader list
##
##


count_list = [0]*len(leader)
indices = [0]*len(leader)

#for i_lea,val_lea in enumerate(leader):
i_count_list = 0
while len(leader) > 0:
    #print i_lea,val_lea

    count_list[i_count_list] = leader.count(leader[0])
    #print 'count_list: '+ str(count_list)
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(leader) if x == leader[0]]
    #print 'indices: '+ str(indices)
    for i in xrange(len(indices)):
        #print 'leader before del: '+ str(leader)
        del leader[leader.index(leader[0])]
        #print 'leader after del: '+ str(leader)
    #print 'leader: '+ str(leader)
    i_count_list = i_count_list+1
    #print 'i_count_list: ' + str(i_count_list)
print 'calc time: '+ str(time.time() - start)+ 's'

sorted_count_list = sorted(count_list, key=int, reverse=True)
print sorted_count_list[0:5]
print datetime.datetime.now()
```

Here is the small test file:

```
1 4

2 8

3 6

4 7

5 2

6 9

7 1

8 5

8 6

9 7

9 3
```

Here is the correct partial result of small test file:

```
calc time: 0.121000051498s
[3, 3, 3, 0, 0]
2017-01-19 08:07:44.802000
```

Comment: Why are you using `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`? It seems likely that your program is encountering an error of some sort, but since you used the former, you're not seeing the error messages or regular `print` output because it provides no `stderr` (or `stdout`) output streams. `pythonw.exe` is for GUI programs, which are expected to display all information graphically.

Comment: I try again and use the python(command line) . "python.exe has stopped working " occurs in the end@martineau

Comment: The "stopped working" message is from the operating system. The interpreter crashing will also prevent any Python error messages from printing. I was going to try to run your script myself using the large input data file, but cannot download it—keep getting `AccessDenied` error messages. Anyhow, I suspect it's due (ironically) to a stackoverflow issue since the `DFS_Loop()` function is recursive.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Martineau. I modified the link to the large input data. If you want to try again, you can just copy this url [http://pan.baidu.com/s/1i5Hmf5N] in your brower and download it with instruction. @martineau

Comment: The new link doesn't work either, I am now getting the message "啊哦，你所访问的页面不存在了。" Try using http://pastebin.com instead.

Comment: It works when I right click http://pan.baidu.com/s/1i5Hmf5N. I'm getting "stolen content from pastebin.com. your request has been blocked! visit pastebin.com for the original content." when I click pastebin.com . Maybe it would be better when I use google drive. Thank you all the same.Mr. Martineau@martineau

Comment: May have something to do with you being in China...